# HTML input tag, cannot type

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have been struggling with this for a couple of days. I am pretty sure it's something simple, but I just can't see it.
On [this page](http://ioniki.com/en/pl.php?id=895&l=6) there is a form that users can use to send a message. Click on the grey Contact icon to see it.
The form used to work fine, but now I cannot type into any fields. Selecting an autocomplete value works though.
I have tried disabling some Javascript, adding a z-index value to the fields, but to no avail.
Can someone please take a look and tell me what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me. Opera 29.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 42.0 and FF 37.0.2

Comment: You mean you can actually type in the boxes? Unfortunately, Firefox and Chrome 42 seem be affected though.

Comment: @Callum. and others : he means the "contact"-button in the rightern column and not the "contact"-menu option.

Comment: @Jordumus, I know, that was the one I tested, and it works fine on my end ^^

Comment: @Callum. well, it is fixed now, with my answer below, it works here as well now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too eager to restrict the user..

This code is the problem:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {          
        //(...)
        toggleArrows();
    }
            return false;
});
```

If the button IS NOT keyCode 39, you deny the button functionality.
Just remove the `return false` and your problem will be gone.

Edit: I just noticed you have 2 keydown events, one checking for keycode 37 and one for 39. Don't do that! You should do it this way:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {          
        //(...)
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
       //(...)
    }

});
```

And, again, get rid of the `return false;`.

JSFiddle to show the result: http://jsfiddle.net/xr2stb0k/
First checkbox is restricted with `return false` (except for the letter "a"), second one isn't.

Comment: You are THE man! I kept overlooking that little thing! SOLVED!